# How can i compile this into an APK?

Tags: android

I've been trying for the past day to try and compile this fork of a GitHub repository into an APK but I just can't seem to do it. Can anyone tell me what to do? here's the link to the GitHub https://github.com/charlieb/aprsdroid/tree/digirig

I've tried following the guide on the main repository at https://github.com/ge0rg/aprsdroid/wiki/Developer but i'm having trouble understanding how to install either ProGuard or the gradle plugin for Scala. I've also tried to google other answers and they just haven't worked.

The specific error I'm getting in Android Studio is "repository 'github.com/charlieb/aprsdroid/tree/digirig' not found"

Comment: please post a specific error or where in the instructions from the guide you are stuck.

Comment: this is the specific error, "repository 'https://github.com/charlieb/aprsdroid/tree/digirig/' not found". this is the guide i'm using, https://github.com/ge0rg/aprsdroid/wiki/Developer, i'm stuck at the part where i need to install both proguard and the gradle plugin for scala

Comment: edit the question with the info in your comment please.